# AngularJS: How to determine is a model disabled or not

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and some fields get disabled with various conditions. Is there a way to determine is a model disabled (without running the same `ng-disabled` condition in the controller)?

Comment: I dont think so, use the same condition

Comment: Can you provide more information? Or some code?

Comment: Its the elements that is disabled not the model. http://plnkr.co/edit/tlvJsQ78weg0kfrCb1mZ?p=preview In the plnkr you will see that model is alive even if the element is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a form in your view, there would be a form object with the name you specified for the form on your controller scope which you can access inside your controller.

However you cannot access attributes (disabled is an attribute on your input) that from controller level (vs you can easily access input attributes from a directive):

```
app.directive('mydir', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require: '^form',        
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
            var allDisabledInputs = $(formCtrl).find(':input:disabled');

            //do stuff here
        }
    };
});
```

And on your form:

```
<form name="someForm" my-dir >
    <input name="input1"  />
    <input name="input2" disabled />
</form>
```